# Math GRE: Calculus Textbooks - is Spivak + Stewart + Rudin sufficient?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, gre-exam

Recently, I splurged and spent $1000 in math textbooks in preparation for the Mathematics GRE subject test. So far, in terms of calculus books, I have purchased Spivak, Stewart, and Baby Rudin.

Is this sufficient preparation for the Math GRE or do I need to get my hands on Apostol?

FYI: I am extremely familiar with the univariate calculus and real analysis material. Multivariate, not so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stewart's Calculus will prepare you for the calculus questions in the [GRE](http://www.ets.org/gre/subject/about/content/mathematics), while Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis will prepare you for the introductory real analysis questions in it.